# What is the use of preg_match('/(benchmark|sleep)/i', $id)

Tags: php, sql-injection, ddos

I today i start to read different articles about SQLi and DoS/DdoS to know how to protect my site and i found this thing :

Link: [link to the article](http://hi.baidu.com/secbug/blog/item/01037efad2015168024f5662.html)

```
 // DB connection

    // $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,pass FROM users WHERE id = $id")
 or die("Error");

    if($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
     $_SESSION['name'] = $data['name'];



    if(preg_match('/(benchmark|sleep)/i', $id))
     exit('attack'); // no timing
```

I want to know the use of this.Also after this the guy show how to bypass it and i want to know if PDO is secury?

Comment: you should also read up on mysql injection and use prepared statements instead of the mysql_* functions or at least use `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: Oh.. This is (10000%) a wrong usage of $id, is a numeric field, then do a casting OR escape value will do ...

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone but i use PDO so i dont use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: You can read about `preg_match` in the PHP manual, it should give you some pointers: http://php.net/preg_match - Your question is rather broad, you should re-word it to make more clear what exactly your issue is.

Comment: @Lawrence mysql_real_escape_string won't help with this code. Go figure. And it is NOT because something wrong with mysql_* functions but with PHP users who just have no idea how to use them.

Answer (score 1):

`if(preg_match('/(benchmark|sleep)/i', $id))` checks if the `$id` matches the strings `benchmark` or `sleep` (the i stands for case-insensitive).

In the context it's presented I'd say this makes no sense what so ever though... I'd rather do this, and be done with it:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];

$result = mysql_query('SELECT id,name,pass FROM users WHERE id = '.$id);
```

Notice I cast the id to an int, so if it's anything else it should just end up being 0, which most likely doesn't match anything since id columns usually starts on 1 (from my experience anyways).

Comment: For the same purpose, I use the `intval` function: `$id = intval($_GET['id']);`

Comment: It worths mentioning that the regular expression would match `benchmark` or `sleep` at any point of the string (it would match "somesleeps", for example)... to match only the exact words, the regex would be `/^(benchmark|sleep)$/i`

Comment: @J.Bruni matching exact words makes no sense in this context.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: indeed, makes no sense from the security point of view; I am only clarifying what the answer says, and "teaching" a two cents bit about regular expressions

Comment: I don't use any of these "parametrization" stuff like PDO or anything else. I do use the "placeholder" approach. Usually, simple like this: `$sql = sprintf('SELECT field FROM table WHERE somefield = "%1$s";', intval($param));`, where the "placeholder" can be anything... a comma-separated list of values for an INSERT or IN clause, a string value, "ASC" or "DESC" for an ORDER BY direction... just **ANYTHING**! [continues...]

Comment: And, of course, each parameter replacing each placeholder will have its unique special treatment, going from an `intval` to a specific whitelisting or escaping function (a special case, for example, is to prepare a string for "LIKE" clauses)... we simply can't generalize, each case is a case, from simple to complex. We may want to dynamically build any part of the query, and for each part there is an appropriate approach.

Comment: So if i use PDO and bindParam() am i safe ?

Comment: @MarianPetrov Probably yes. I'd probably use `bindValue` instead though. Looks simpler :)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know the use of this

**That's quite silly and apparently useless attempt to detect a possible SQL injection** which is supposed to run a resource-consuming query.

> Also after this the guy show how to bypass it

No wonder.
Once you have a code open to injection, thaere are thousands methods to run it.

**The only your concern should be injection in general**.

Once you protected - no ddos injection would be possible.

> i want to know if PDO is secury?

First, it is not PDO secure, but strict and constant use of **prepared statements** considered secure.

Second, **[nope, prepared statements helps only half the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/285587)**

Comment: Hey, you linked us to an "edit" page! :) The link shoud be http://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/370290

Comment: I made a mistake, too! My latest two comments saying I also apply a **placeholder** approach were supposed to be done for your answer (not the other where the comments were added)...

Comment: Well, feel free to move it here. I am using the same (yet more powerful) approach

Comment: So if i use PDO and bindParam() am i safe ?

Comment: @Marian Please follow the link I am emphasized  especially for your convenience. Thank you in advance.